# I have a doc library that won't change to the new experience when I select it in Advanced Settings.

Tags: document-library

Any ideas what is preventing it from changing?  It stays in the classic view.
It doesn't change when we switch the entire site to the New Experience, either.

Answer (score 0):

Then you are probably using some of the features that cause it to revert back to classic view as detailed [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Differences-between-classic-and-new-experiences-for-lists-and-document-libraries-30e1aab0-a5cc-4363-b7f2-09e2ae07d4dc?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1).

> Use auto-detect to automatically return to classic view
>
> As an admin, you can choose to show classic view only, or use the new
> experience but automatically return to classic view when certain
> features are used. These features are:
>
> Navigation features Metadata navigation and filtering – All libraries
> on sites that have this feature enabled are shown in classic view.
>
> Column types External data columns
>
> Geolocation columns
>
> Publishing columns (Publishing HTML, Publishing Image, Publishing
> Hyperlink)
>
> Permissions Limited-access user permission lockdown mode
>
> Customizations JSLink code on fields
>
> CustomActions that include ScriptBlock or ScriptSrc properties

Comment: Thanks, Eric.  I'm still not able to tell anything different from the library that doesn't switch to all the others that do, except that the library that doesn't switch has a content type associated with it.  I tried to delete the content type from the doc library, but get an error and haven't been able to resolve why.  I'm not going to worry about one doc lib at this point.